# .dev domains don't resolve

Tags: macos, dns, hosts-file

I noticed today that no `.dev` domains will resolve in any browser on my MacBook while trying to access [web.dev](https://web.dev); they all say “__.dev refused to connect.” I did a quick google search for [`site:.dev`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:.dev), and all of the listed domains produce the same error, despite the fact that I can load them all from my phone on the same network. I'm using `1.1.1.1` as my DNS server but had the same issue even after changing my DNS server. I looked in `/etc/hosts` and didn’t find anything relevant. What could be the issue?

Comment: I used .local for similar work in the past.  The link below shows that .dev TLD may have have been deprecated recently.  https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd

Comment: I'm not trying to spoof it for development, I'm trying to connect to a real domain on the internet. The `dev` behavior that got deprecated was the redirection to localhost that a lot of devs used to use. I don't think I ever had such a thing configured on my machine, though it's possible I might have.

Answer (score 63):

I'd answered this in another comment, but found this answer in another thread helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223730

I'm answering here as Google led me here first, and so I can put some extra context for old Rails devs. If you used Pow or a similar service, it had you put a file in `/etc/resolver` called `dev` that looks a bit like this:

```
# Lovingly generated by Pow
nameserver 127.0.0.1
port 20560
```

Deleting the file (`sudo rm /etc/resolver/dev`) will clear this issue up.

Comment: Awesome, that did it for me. I've tried everything else, including uninstalling pow, but this file was never mentioned anywhere and is not removed during uninstallation.

Comment: PS: this was especially frustrating because while `.dev` domains did not resolve in *any* browser, they resolved just fine on the terminal, using `host` or `nslookup`.

Comment: this made my day

Comment: I wasted so much time on this issue, thank you for posting. Life saver.

Comment: This was blocking me from submitting tickets to AWS ...   What a head scratcher!

Answer (score 2):

Try with `https://` instead of `http://` in the address bar. And check the firewall, and try another browser. Try disabling the browser's parental controls and extensions. Opening an "incognito window" or secure browsing session does that, unless you enabled extensions there too.

Also clear the browser cache. Apparently, that's now the preferred, if not the only, way to clear 301 redirects.

To make sure DNS is working, drop to a terminal and type `dig web.dev`. The dig command queries the DNS server for detailed address information. Try going directly to the listed IP address in the `ANSWER SECTION`, in this case, https://216.239.34.21.

```
web.dev.        162 IN  A   216.239.34.21
```

Update: Also check that a DNS server, such as `dnsmasq`, isn't configured to direct `.dev` to localhost in `dnsmasq.conf` or similar. Change `dev` to `test`, `invalid`, or `localhost` as per [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606).

```
#address=/dev/127.0.0.1
address=/test/127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Incognito and `https` don't fix the problem. `dig` does resolve the right IP. Navigating directly there yields a 404 because of the way Google has their webserver for the site set up, though

Comment: That's interesting. Can you `ping -c 1 web.dev` and get the right address? If so, that probably rules out the OS resolvers and firewalls. Are you using Chrome or Safari? DesktopServer could also be misconfiguired and running. There is information on changing the .dev TLD  https://docs.serverpress.com/article/232-how-to-change-top-level-domain-dev-extension-google-chrome-users

Comment: `ping -c 1 web.dev` shows it resolving to `localhost` (`PING web.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes`)

Comment: I've never used any program called `DesktopServer`

Comment: @LukeTaylor Did you ever manage to resolve this?

Comment: I think the issue resolved itself as dev domains rolled out further. I own a .dev domain which resolves correctly

Comment: For the sake of continuity, I'd found another solution for this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223730

The short of it is I used to use Pow for Rails development, which treated .dev as a local domain. Never took it out, so it was sitting there in `/etc/resolver`